# What is the best way to make a full page Silverlight web part in SharePoint 2010

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I want to make a silverlight web part hosted in SharePoint 2010 that will take up the entire screen.  I know how to get rid of all the SharePoint navigation through CSS or a custom master page, but I'm struggling with how to get a web part zone to grow to the full height available.  I've messed around with using CSS or jquery to set the heights of the various tables and divs that wrap a web part and haven't found a good solution.  Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about not using a webpart, and just embedding the Silverlight application into an empty page with an empty masterpage?

You can grab the html or aspx page that Visual Studio generates when you create an new Silverlight project.

Comment: I'm targeting SharePoint Online (Office365) so I have to go with a sandboxed solution.  Application Pages aren't an option, but site pages are which is how I'm doing this right now.  I'll look into whether I can just put the Silverlight object tags directly into the Site Page.

Comment: Looks like there are still going to be some divs and tables to adjust the height of, so for now I'm just setting the size. Here's what the style looks like to hide the sharepoint nav:
<style type="text/css">
/*** Hide the Ribbon and Quick Launch ***/
#s4-titlerow, /* Top Nav */   
#s4-ribbonrow, /* Ribbon */
#s4-leftpanel, /* Quick Launch */ 
.s4-notdlg /* non-dialog elements */
{
    DISPLAY: none;
}  
     
.s4-ca {  
    MARGIN-LEFT: 0px;
}
</style>

Comment: and here's an example of dropping the Silverlight in without a web part:

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="900px" height="675px">
    <param name="source" value="http://myserver/myfolder/myapplication.xap"/>
     </object>
    </div>
</asp:Content>

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to get a new master page for this purpose. You can get the minimal master page here:

http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/starter-master-pages-for-sharepoint.html

Comment: I don't think the master page alone will help since I know ways to get rid of the SP navigation.  I'm familiar with the starter master pages so yes that is a good place to start.  It is really getting the web part zone to take the full vertical space that is the challenge, though getting the empty master in place first will help.